# NodeJs - TypeError: Post is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on NodeJs application it's blog application. I am trying to save posts in database and I am getting this error after submitting form:

```
TypeError: Post is not a constructor
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="/admin/posts/create" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter The Title">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
      <option value="public">Public</option>
      <option value="private">Private</option>
      <option value="draft">Draft</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Content</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your content here" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>


  <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="submit">Create Post</button>

</form>
```

Here is controller part

**adminController.js**

```
const Post = require('../models/postModel').Post;

module.exports = {
    index: (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/index');
    },

    getPosts: (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/posts/index');
    },

    submitPosts: (req, res) => {
        const newPost = new Post({
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
            status: req.body.status   
        });

        newPost.save().then(post => {
            req.flash('success-message', 'Post created successfully.');
            res.redirect('/admin/posts');
        });

    },

    createPosts: (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/posts/create');
    }
};
```

I'm not sure why am I getting this error as imported model as

```
const Post = require('../models/postModel').Post;
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I had to change

```
const Post = require('../models/postModel').Post;
```

to

```
const Post = require('../models/postModel');
```

and my code works just fine.

Whit `.Post` I thought that it would be as using it as object but it was fine just to import it as

`const Post = require('../models/postModel');`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and what I did wrong was just a typo. I wrote `module.export = Post;` instead of `module.exports = Post;`

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that you are are importing it wrong.

`mongoose.model("Post" , postSchema);`
If you are using something like this to export, then your are importing it wrong.
Instead use this to import it
`const Post = mongoose.model("Post");`

It sure did solve my error

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you're not aware, `const` means 'constant', and is used for immutable variables; it doesn't mean `constructor`, as it sounds like you're implying.

And the part that's throwing the error is

```
const newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        status: req.body.status   
    });
```

And it's exactly what it's telling you, `Post` is not a constructor, so you cannot create an object with it using the `new` keyword. We would need to see the definition of `Post` in the 'models/postModel/' file to know exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I am aware of it.. and I don't know why for you sounds like I'm implying on it. I found answer to my question! It's in answers but also thanks for your help :)

Comment: I didn't mean to offend; it was the statement "I'm not sure why am I getting this error as I declared const" that made me suspect that, as I'm not sure what declaring it as a constant would have to do with it being a constructor or not.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have written "as I imported post model" maybe would be better to understand cuz now I noticed that maybe it can confuse someone. Not offended at all thanks for your note I will edit my question to maybe help others better.